# POST to PHP for username and password validation issue

Tags: php, objective-c

I have been trying to figure out what is wrong and I just can't figure it out.

I am trying to make the use of a login functionality in my app, but for some reason, when sending a request, the server does not get anything and it does not return anything.

This is my code to make the POST into php:

```
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@",usernameTxtField.text];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)postData.length];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://iamitman/interdev/ScannApp/login.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(conn) {
        NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
    }
```

And this is my simple php file:

```
    <?php  
 require "conn.php";  
$user_name = $_POST['username']; 

$query = "SELECT * FROM ClientMain";

$result =  mysql_query($query);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO  `ClientMain` (`ClntName`)
VALUES ('$user_name');");

echo$user_name;
?>
```

When I press on my logon button, I don't see the POST results on phpMyAdmin.

What am I missing? Can someone give me any pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: so, what happens when you try it on your server rather than phpmyadmin? check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: How is this question related to phpmyadmin? a) Your "simple php file" doesn't interact with MySQL. b) Your objective-c code doesn't show or process the response for the request. c) Does your log file contain the "Connection successful" or the "Connection could not be made" message?

Comment: I might be missing something but: What does phpMyAdmin have to do with this? You're POSTing to a URL and simply echoing out one of the posted vars on that page - there are no database insertions or anything alike in your posted code?

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin to see what values are being posted into the database. See my updated question.

Comment: The mysql_* extension is deprecated and is not present anymore in the php 7 release. You better [choose another api](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) to interact with your MySQL server.

Comment: Not an answer, but a few helpful things: a) don't blindly trust $_POST vars for mysql queries (SQL Injection) b) as @VolkerK pointed out, mysql_* functions are deprecated c) Add some error checking to your code (eg. check for mysql errors on the insert and print out the http response of your connection in objective-c)

Comment: You are open to SQL injections with this. Is `ClntName` unique? Is your `POST` populated?

Comment: @VolkerK right, and PDO is preferable

Answer (score 0):

Example script using [PDO](http://docs.php.net/pdo) instead of the deprecated mysql_* extension and some error handling (though no sanity checks).

```
<?php
if ( !isset($_POST['username']) ) {
    header('Unprocessable Entity', true, 422);
    die('...missing parameter "username" ...');
}
else {
    // adjust database host, dbname and credentials
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly', array(
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>false,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY=>false,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ));

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('
        INSERT INTO
            `ClientMain`
            (`ClntName`)
        VALUES
            (?)
    ');
    $stmt->execute( array($_POST['username']) );
    echo '... ', htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']), ' ...';
}
```

Test this script first via a "common" webbrowser with

```
<form method="POST" action="...">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="username" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

(replace ... by the actual url) and check the response. Only when this is working as intended try again with the objective-c application.

Comment: Ok. I am trying to understand with all the conversation going on. I'll check and get back. Thank you